# Check if different columns of two dataframes are equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, filter

I want to compare two columns that don't have the same name and are in two different dataframes and finally create a new column by assigning True/False if the values match.

Before that, i also want to filter one of the columns.

More informations below :

*df1.answer* -> i want to filter *answer* such as : **!= -1** (*answer* takes 3 values : 1,2,-1)

*df2.correct_answer*

I did this but it says that they don't have the same name. Plus i don't know how to integrate the filter. I suppose there is a better way to do it:

```
a = df1.query('answer !=-1')

df2['correct']= np.where(df2['correct_answer'] == df1['answer'],'True','False') 

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add a sample of both the dataframes along with the output?

Comment: you are getting this error bcz the length of both Series are different

Comment: To compare column values of two different dataframes, you need to have an index (a key) that you use to match rows between dataframes before to compare them (`pd.merge`). Except if your relation between your 2 dataframes is one-to-one (`pd.concat`)